# PHP/MySQL Multidimensional/Associative Arrays 3 Trial Balance

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'm currently working on an accounting code that will print out a Trial Balance based on data stored in MySql. I can't seem to get my head around the arrays that should get the trial balance displayed correctly. The data-set looks somewhat like this:

id |     account      |        amount        |        paymode     
1         TUITION                 5000                      Cheque  
2          TUITION                   2000                      Cash   
3          Repairs                      500                       Cash

The output of the trial balance should display in double entry format like this:

ACCOUNT      |        DEBIT        |        CREDIT     
Bank                       5000
Cash                       2000                 500
TUITION                                         7000    
Repairs                     500

Please note above that two accounts(Bank and Cash) have to be generated automatically by code depending on the paymode field...and their values(5000 and 2000 in this case) are also dependent on the values found under the "amount" column.

So my current code looks like this so far: (It outputs accounts in their total but only on the DEBIT side)

```
// Make the query(Get Accounts and Totals):
$rein = @mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT account, amount, paymode FROM tbl_finance"); // Run the query.

$bg = '#eeeeee';
$accarr = array();
while($rowin = mysqli_fetch_array($rein, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if(!isset($accarr[$rowin['type']])) {
    $accarr[$rowin['type']]['amount'] = 0;
}
$sum = $rowin['amount_paid'];
$accarr[$rowin['type']]['amount'] += $sum;
$accarr[$rowin['type']]['paymode'] = $rowin['payterm'];
} // End While
mysqli_free_result($rein);
print_r($accarr);

echo '
<table>
<tr>
    <td align="left"><b>ACCOUNT</b></td>
    <td align="right"><b>DEBIT</b></td>
    <td align="right"><b>CREDIT</b></td>
</tr>
';

$bg = '#eeeeee';
foreach($accarr as $acc => $data) {
$bg = ($bg=='#eeeeee' ? '#ffffff' : '#eeeeee');

echo '
<tr bgcolor="'. $bg .'">
    <td align="left">'. $acc .'</td>
        <td align="right">'. $data['amount'] .'</td>
</tr>
';
} // End foreach

echo '</table>';
```

Edit: The current output of above statement:

ACCOUNT      |        DEBIT        |        CREDIT     
TUITION                   7000    
Repairs                     500

Question: How can the data-set above be used to output data as displayed above(aligned to DEBIT and CREDIT where appropriate)?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you also paste your current output that you are getting now? Also, how do we know if a particular account is _debit_ or _credit_?

Comment: See the guidelines abpout pasting code here

Comment: @cheezburger, should i add another column which will explicitly point out if Dr or Cr? If so(assuming such a column exists) how will the code look like?

Comment: @Brian Yes, I think your table needs another column to point out which of the account is debited and which is credited. I'll try writing up the code assuming it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok (I should've paid more concentration during those accounts lectures). Now I don't know if an account (except Bank and Cash) can have debit and credit at the same time, but since your example entries didn't indicate, I'm guessing it doesn't. Also, the below code assumes (like indicated in the comment above) that you have a column (I named it `transaction`) which says whether it's a `Dr` or `Cr` entry.

```
//this array will hold bank and cash values
$main_acc=array('bank'=>array('Dr'=>0,'Cr'=>0), 'cash'=>array('Dr'=>0,'Cr'=>0));

//this one to hold other accounts and their amounts, transaction etc.
$acc = array();
while($rowin = mysqli_fetch_array($rein, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    /* store bank transaction type and amount */
    if($rowin['paymode']=='Cheque'){
        $main_acc['bank'][$rowin['transaction']] =$main_acc['bank'][$rowin['transaction']] + $rowin['amount'];
    }
    /* store cash transaction type and amount */
    if($rowin['paymode']=='Cash'){
        $main_acc['cash'][$rowin['transaction']] = $main_acc['cash'][$rowin['transaction']] + $rowin['amount'];
    }
    /* store other account transaction type and increment
       amount if already exists */
    if(isset($acc[$rowin['account']])){
        $acc[$rowin['account']]['amount'] = $acc[$rowin['account']]['amount'] +$rowin['amount'];
    }
    else
    {
        $acc[$rowin['account']]['trans'] = $rowin['transaction'];
        $acc[$rowin['account']]['amount'] = $rowin['amount'];

    }

}

echo '
<table>
<tr>
    <td align="left"><b>ACCOUNT</b></td>
    <td align="right"><b>DEBIT</b></td>
    <td align="right"><b>CREDIT</b></td>
</tr>
';

$bg = '#eeeeee';
//displaying bank and cash
foreach($main_acc as $key=>$val){

            $bg = ($bg=='#eeeeee') ? '#ffffff' : '#eeeeee';
            echo '<tr bgcolor="'. $bg .'">
                    <td align="left">'. $key .'</td>
                    <td align="left">'. (($val['Cr']!=0)?$val['Cr']:'') .'</td>
                    <td align="right">'. (($val['Dr']!=0)?$val['Dr']:'').'</td>
                  </tr>
        ';
}

//displaying other accounts
foreach($acc as $key=>$val){

            $bg = ($bg=='#eeeeee') ? '#ffffff' : '#eeeeee';
            echo '<tr bgcolor="'. $bg .'">
                    <td align="left">'. $key .'</td>
                    <td align="left">'. (($val['trans']=='Dr')?$val['amount']:'') .'</td>
                    <td align="right">'. (($val['trans']=='Cr')?$val['amount']:'') .'</td>
                  </tr>
        ';
}
echo '</table>';
```

#### Output:

```
ACCOUNT DEBIT   CREDIT
bank    5000    
cash    2000      500
TUITION          7000
Repairs 500
```

Comment: Thank you @Cheezburger for your solid answer...i am also uneasy about predetermining an accounts transaction type... There is a nice tutorial course on accounting you can learn from. http://www.lapasserelle.com/online_courses/accounting/index.html and Dr/Cr Chart on http://www.accountrain.com/debit_credit.html

Comment: @Brian You may find [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17197/what-is-a-common-way-to-save-debit-and-credit-information) helpful for how to store 'debit' 'credit' information on the DB. Feel free to ask on that site for advice too.